# Robot.txt can get all soft404s fixed?

Tags: 404, soft-404

I got many soft404 in Google webmaster Tools, and those webpages aren't existing any more. thus I am unable to insert  `<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">` into my pages, and I've been searching a while but didn't get some valuable clues.

There are about 100 URLs are soft 404, to redirect them all one by one is a bit silly as it would cost too much time for me.

If I just add those links into `robots.txt` like below

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /mysite.asp
Disallow: /mysite-more.html
```

if this way will fix all soft404s solidly? or if there is a way to change all soft404 to hard404?

Comment: My understanding is that this will stop Google from crawling them.  It does not stop it from indexing them, if there are references to them.  So, its important to make sure that nothing on your site references them.  There are tools around that will give you the "found on page" references for these links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow. I think I got what you are saying, but there are some missing pieces so please bear with me.

Soft 404 errors are often something really stupid like having the phrase *not found* in your content. That drives me nuts! It happens to me all the time. It cannot occur unless Google sees a page and (likely) is getting a page with *not found* but no actual 404 response header. Something is interrupting the normal 404 error process. This we know because you tell us that the pages do not exist.

I am not sure how a non-existing page can have soft 404 unless it is being redirected or triggering a custom 404 error that is not working properly. If this is the case, then remove the redirect or custom 404 and let a *real* 404 happen. It may take take about 30 days or so for Google to stop looking for these pages. But it will clear up in time.

Comment: Thanks very much for taking time to answer my question. Cannot find any thing redirected. odd thing! If possible to use robot.txt to ask google to ignore / crawl specific pages?

Comment: Yes you can. I did not address that part of your question because it appears that there is something else wrong. You can enter each page one per line (as you know) or if there is a whole directory then you can specify that. Check your ErrorDocument directive (if you can) in your .htaccess or specific site configuration file under /etc/apache2/sites-available/. I am making the assumption you are using Apache. Any other configuration I would not know. You are making sure that it does not have something funky, wonky, googlie, whacky, or just plain weirded out.

Comment: Anytime! Keep an eye out for something that may be interfering with the normal 404 error process. That you can take some time on. The robots.txt thing will likely keep you busy enough for a while.